# Stitcher API seems to be missing from my python opencv bindings

Tags: python, opencv

For some reason, the stitcher bindings seem to be missing from my opencv python bindings. For example, this code:

```
import cv2
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)
foo = cv2.imread("foo.png")
bar = cv2.imread("bar.png")
result = stitcher.stitch((foo,bar))

cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", result[1])
```

results in this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createStitcher'
```

Running a help(cv2) within the python interpreter also shows that the function simply is not there.

Comment: What OpenCV version are you running?

Comment: Not sure if this was a bug or not, but it seemed to be there when i ran python3 instead of python.

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple versions of Python installed with possibly multiple versions of OpenCV. I would suggest using virtual environments to ensure that you're always working with the versions of libs that you expect :)

Answer (score 4):

It is probably because you are using OpenCV 4.

If you are using OpenCV 4 you should use `cv2.Stitcher_create()` (also `cv2.Stitcher.create()` should work).

If you are using OpenCV 3 you should use `cv2.createStitcher()` as you did.

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing you recently upgraded your Cv2 version (same here). To be safe go ahead and pip uninstall all your Cv2 stuff and then reinstall the newest version. Look through the Cv2 source code for Stitcher and you will find that you need to use a new syntax to create an instance. Here is code that will stitch images in a directory:

```
import cv2
import os
import re

def tryint(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return s

def alphanum_key(s):
    return [tryint(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', s)]

def sort_nicely(l):
    l.sort(key=alphanum_key)
    return l


directory = "Image/Directory"
fileNameKeys = ['File','Names','Contain','These','Strings']


dirList = sort_nicely([file for file in os.listdir(directory) if all(substring in file for substring in fileNameKeys)])
images = [cv2.imread(directory + '/' + imageFile) for imageFile in dirList if True]
print(dirList)


#################################
stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create()
#################################


stitchOut = stitcher.stitch(images)
print("Stitcher exit status = " + str(stitchOut[0]))
print("Hit any Key to continue and save image")
cv2.imshow('Stitched Image', stitchOut[1])
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite(directory + "/" + "STITCH.png", stitchOut[1])
```